# Why does Redhat's daemon function not have a group setting?

Tags: rhel, init-script, daemon

**Background:**

I'm a Ubuntu/Debian fan and most of my development experience has been on that platform but my current employer uses Redhat. I needed to write a simple init.d script and want the resulting program to run as an unprivileged user. Most resources I found suggest using the daemon function in lieu of start-stop-daemon.

**Question:**

Why doesn't the daemon function have an option to set the group like the start-stop-daemon? I'm sure there must be a reason for this, just not sure what that reason is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly change the daemon function to set the group or you can write your own `mydaemon` function to do it.

Or in a simplest possible way just call the `runuser` command that `daemon()` uses to start your program with particular `UID` and `GID`

Comment: So there is no reason why it couldn't/shouldn't set group, for what ever reason it just doesn't?

Comment: @Jacks_Depression By default it should set the default group for the user as well.  But if it doesn't you can change it.